# how to put year as date tick in matlab

Tags: matlab, date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6UDX.jpg)  1.hi, i am trying to put date tick in x axis using MATLAB 2010, date range is 2011/2012, but i have error in year format in x axis, data in Excel file, the code is below
thanks to help me

```
set(figure,'Color','white')
startDate = datenum(txt(w+2));
endDate = datenum(txt(end));
xData = linspace(startDate,endDate,length(de));
str = datestr(xData, 'mmm-yyyy');
plot(xData,de,'b',xData,re,'k')
NumTicks = 12;[enter image description here][1]
L = get(gca,'XLim');
set(gca,'XTick',linspace(L(1),L(2),NumTicks))
datetick('x','mmm yyyy','keeplimits', 'keepticks')
xticklabel_rotate;
set(gca,'XMinorTick','on','YMinorTick','on')
y_labels = get(gca, 'YTick');
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', y_labels); [year format error][1]
```

Comment: What is the error and at what line are you getting it? What are the states of the variables at that line.

Comment: do you lock in figure, year format?

Comment: date range is 2011 to 2012, but lock in figure as 0021, 0023,,,,,,,,:!!!!!

Comment: What are your values for `startDate` and `endDate`? And for `txt(w+2)` and `txt(end)`?

Comment: how can i put data, which are in Excel file?

Comment: @Pencil Pen just give the data as code, so for instance: `xx = [today-3;today-2;today-1;today]` and `yy = [1;2;3;4]` might accurately describe your time series data.

Comment: @Pencil Pen That will help us to recreate your chart.  I would suspect though that Dan's question is an important one.  What are your values for `startDate` and `endDate`?

Comment: startDate=01/08/2011, endDate=16/09/2012, w=905

Comment: pleas give me your email, to send you code and excel file,

Comment: @PencilPen `startDate` is an integer not a string nor a date! And I asked for `txt(w+2)` not `w`. I want the ***EXACT*** outputs that typing those variable names into the command line gives you. What you have provided us is useless. Anyway, if your dates come from Excel then you need to convert them using [`x2mdate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/x2mdate.html?refresh=true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB is going to read `01/08/2011` as `08-Jan-2011` when you convert it to `datenum`.  Try changing the format of your Excel file so that the date is given as `03/14/12` instead of `14/03/12`.  Or you can change your `datenum` command so that it includes the date format, as in: `datenum('01/08/2011','dd/mm/yyyy')`.  That will return `734716`, which is `01-Aug-2011`.

Comment: Thanks to you, god may be blesse you,

Comment: surely ma dear dgoverde

Comment: Hi, Any one can help me to traine neural network with differents algorithms like, GA,SA,Ant-Colony? help me with matlab codes Thanks

Comment: Many here have experience with training neural networks in Matlab. If you ask a specific question and give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, we'll try to help you.